# Extend Array Class with Append method (this ref)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods

I'd like to extend System.Array class to do something like that:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Append( this byte[] dst, byte[] src)
    {
        Array.Resize<byte>(ref dst, dst.Length + src.Length);
        Array.Copy(src, 0, dst, dst.Length - src.Length,src.Length);
        return;
    }
}
```

but "this" is not possible to be referenced ... and on return it turn back as at the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean by ""this" is not possible to be referenced"?

Comment: @JonSkeet You can't have the first parameter of an extension method be pass by reference

Comment: @Servy: That's what I *think* the OP means, but only based on the title. It would have been much clearer if the OP had posted the code that didn't work :(

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "Can I make the first parameter of an extension method a `ref` parameter?" then the answer is no, you can't. (Not in C#, anyway. IIRC, you can in VB - but I'd advise against it.)

From section 10.6.9 of the C# spec:

> The first parameter of an extension method can have no modifiers other than `this`, and the parameter type cannot be a pointer type.

You'd have to return the array instead:

```
public static byte[] Append(this byte[] dst, byte[] src)
{
    Array.Resize(ref dst, dst.Length + src.Length);
    Array.Copy(src, 0, dst, dst.Length - src.Length,src.Length);
    return dst;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
foo = foo.Append(bar);
```

It really feels like you want a `List<byte>` at that point though - and if you're *really* going to make an extension method like this, at least make it generic:

```
public static T[] Append<T>(this T[] dst, T[] src)
{
    Array.Resize(ref dst, dst.Length + src.Length);
    Array.Copy(src, 0, dst, dst.Length - src.Length,src.Length);
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not possible for the implicit parameter of an extension method to have the `ref` modifier.  What you are looking for is simply not possible; you'll need to use a non-extension method to get this behavior, or you'll need to return a new array rather than modifying the implicit reference.